# Assigning boolean value to session attribute in jRuby/ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, jrubyonrails

How to assign a boolean value to a session attribute and read/check it from another place?

is this the correct way??

Assigning :

```
   <% session[:contacts_available]=true %>
```

Checking the value :

```
   <% if session[:contacts_available]? %> 
       <p> Donec interdum turpis eget leo lobortis, sit amet lacinia ante vulputate. Maecenas hendrerit 
         euismod nulla in semper. Donec arcu nibh, faucibus at posuere id, dapibus non tellus. </p>

   <% else %>  
       <p> You're logged in as : <%= current_user.email %> <%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path %> </p>
       <p> Welcome to our service. You currently don't have any contact details under your username. 
       Please fill the below form to show the first contact detail of yours.  </p>

   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to explicitly check for it being `true`, not `truthy`:

```
 <% if session[:contacts_available] == true %>
```

or

```
 <% if TrueClass === session[:contacts_available] %>
```

If [`truthy`](https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362) (nor `false` neither `nil`) is enough:

```
 <% if session[:contacts_available] %>
```

The question mark is intended to be used in *method name* endings by convention, one should not put it “just in case.”

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can assign boolean to session, to check it in if statement, remove `?`.

```
  session[:contacts_available] ? "Found" : "Not Found"

 OR

   <% if session[:contacts_available] %> 
       <p> Yeah Contact Found </p>    
   <% else %>  
       <p>Contacts not found </p>
   <% end %>
```

Boolean:

```
true == true # returns true

false == true # returns false
```

If statement:

```
#session[:contacts_available] = true

if true 
   puts "True"
else 
   puts "false"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try. you should not require `?` in `session[:contacts_available]?`

I think you want to check it presence true so `if true` is execute the block else execute other one

```
 <% if session[:contacts_available] %> 
       <p> Donec interdum turpis eget leo lobortis, sit amet lacinia ante vulputate. Maecenas hendrerit 
     euismod nulla in semper. Donec arcu nibh, faucibus at posuere id, dapibus non tellus. </p>    
   <% else %>  
        <p> You're logged in as : <%= current_user.email %> <%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path %> </p>
   <p> Welcome to our service. You currently don't have any contact details under your username. 
   Please fill the below form to show the first contact detail of yours.  </p>
   <% end %>
```